# Help Identify Coax Connector

Tags: connector, identification

Desperately trying to find a receptacle to match these 10-years-old cords which come from a Beckman Coulter FC500 cytometer. Anyone know the name?

The receptacle previously used is labelled "AMP" with a squiggly M.

Requested infos:
Diameter of connector barrel at the end is 4.2mm/.165". Length of gold cap portion is 15.5mm/.610"

The connector seems to be push insertion, with a cheap friction-lock style retention clip on the receptacle (easily bent).

I've included the bag labelled "FOA" but it's electrical, not fiber optic! Could just be a reused bag...

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Wtf. Never seen that thing before. But others may have. To assist them you could take a caliper and add some measures to your question. I.e. diameter and length for a start.

Comment: Also some better pictures (including better cropping) won't hurt, my guess would be something custom though.

Comment: Added requested infos. Sorry my camera can't really focus on really small things that well.

Comment: The connector sockets are marked AMP.  That's part of TE Connectivity.  You might have some luck contacting them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More precisely the are called "Coaxicon" by TE; here's a brochure http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/595245.pdf. Beware that they come in several sizes. It looks like yours are the "miniature" version (there's also "subminiature" and "size 8"). Since it seems you want the PCB-mount socket (there's also a cable mount):

[image]

Comment: Mfg link for the 1st of those part nos: http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-50084-1.html

Answer (score 3):

They are TE connectors, at digikey http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?mpart=201145-4&vendor=17  typically used with backplane connectors, it seems.

[image]

Comment: +1 because Helpful, but OP is looking for the single pin plug/female receptacle.

Comment: Thank you! This is just as helpful. Were you already familiar or did you search for it somehow?

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with this style of connector but I did an image search "te amp coax miniature" and found it